# How to Role-Play an eldritch god?

Tags: fiction, structure, narrative, roleplaying

I am currently trying to figure out how to write the actions of an eldritch god that I've created in a Role-Play setting that I have with a few friends, this setting is mainly based on the SCP Universe, although heavily modified. The god is called Inithrul, and exists all across the universe while being completely undetectable to anyone and anything, the one exception being it's avatar, which is on earth.

This god has existed since before time, before reality as we know it existed, and avoided being shattered into shards by some entity.

Inithrul knew the earliest men, it knew them well, as it was around them for
most of their early time on earth, before it went to sleep around a hundred thousand years ago, only to have itself, and it's avatar, partially awakened by a cult. While this cult managed to awaken Inithrul partially, it failed to wake Inithrul completely due to the cult being stopped by the setting's Global Occult Coalition, because of this Inithrul is limited to a tiny fraction of itself, which still makes it incredibly powerful. further more, it is trapped by an energy field and can not break out.

The avatar in question is feminine in it's outline, has six insect wings, four arms and two legs, it takes this shape as it is the most approachable form it can shape this avatar into while still appealing to it's own perception.

Inithrul's actions in the setting are quite straight-forward, which isn't good, that why I come here, how can I write things to make it more cryptic, random and unknowable? And does anyone have a suggestion on what to do next? (Sorry if my grammar was poor.)

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! We can't give you suggestions on what to do next, as questions on what to write are off-topic here, but we can definitely give you suggestions on how to write from the perspective of an eldritch god.

Answer (score 1):

### Read Lovecraft:

HP Lovecraft is the go-to guy for eldritch gods. There is a certain formula to them, so my answer is based off this formula.

There are a lot of stories, and while the gods are all pretty horrible, they are not always how you imagine them to be. The chief quality of eldritch gods is often their indifference to humans and their societies. One god might eat souls for fun and profit, while another eats people and rebirths them into an immortal form. But the fundamental model is that humans are powerless and something of an afterthought. A human soul is about as significant to it as a snickers bar. It's nice, it's expected to be there for it's use, but there's no emotional significance to it. The death of one human is about as important as the destruction of the world - if it serves a purpose, it is used for that purpose.

So your avatar is unlikely to give a crap about humanity and its petty wants and needs. At best, humans are pets. Humans who serve are rewarded, but you and I might not think of it as a reward. If it does want anything to do with them, it will take the long game, influencing human evolution to become something it wants. Geological time is more important to such beings, and if their inevitable loosing happens in 10, 100, or 1000 years, it doesn't make that much difference.

I'm going to assume your god can always reincarnate a new avatar, but if this is problematic, it will seek out followers to transform into new potential avatars. This would likely take the form of some kind of transitional being, half human, half eldritch, which is then more amenable to manipulation. Lovecraftian stories are full of such servitors, who perform all the petty tasks too lowly for the god. The designated leader of these creatures would be consumed by the god, transformed into a new avatar when the old one perished.